# Attribute to make a given action to accept a given content-type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible in ASP.NET Core MVC to change only certain actions to accept `plain/text` or `application/xml` (ie. `content-type`) with an attribute without changing the default input formatters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, ASP.NET Core only supports JSON or XML. As long as you set the content types of the payload, it should deserialize correctly regardless of the controller action.

If you want support for any other content type (e.g. text/plain) you can create a [custom formatter](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters.md)

Example taken directly from aspnet samples [repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/master/samples/Mvc.Formatters/TextPlainInputFormatter.cs):

```
public class TextPlainInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    public TextPlainInputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add("text/plain");
        SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF8EncodingWithoutBOM);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF16EncodingLittleEndian);
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string);
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
    {
        string data = null;
        using (var streamReader = context.ReaderFactory(context.HttpContext.Request.Body, encoding))
        {
            data = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        return InputFormatterResult.Success(data);
    }
}
```